# How can I count unique terms in a plaintext file case-insensitively?

Tags: python, perl, unix, count, awk

This can be in any high-level language that is likely to be available on a typical unix-like system (Python, Perl, awk, standard unix utils {sort, uniq}, etc). Hopefully it's fast enough to report the total number of unique terms for a 2MB text file.

I only need this for quick sanity-checking, so it doesn't need to be well-engineered.

Remember, case-insensitve.

Thank you guys very much.

Side note: If you use Python, please don't use version 3-only code. The system I'm running it on only has 2.4.4.

Comment: I sometimes wonder how scared people are of python performance. I once wrote a script that took 4GB of dicom images, turned them into PNGs, turned those PNGs into scipy arrays, parsed segmentation files which were turned into scipy arrays as well and saved that stuff to disk - resulting into a 32 GB mountain of integers. 

Was done in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you try to solve the problem yourself? If yes, what problems did you meet? If not, why not?

Comment: When I have to do this problem, the counting is easy. It's the tokenizing where all the trouble creeps in. What is the input like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.4 (possibly it works on earlier systems as well):

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.4
import sys
h = set()
for line in sys.stdin.xreadlines():
  for term in line.split():
    h.add(term)
print len(h)
```

In Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'for (split(" ", $_)) { $H{$_} = 1 } END { print scalar(keys%H), "\n" }' <file.txt
```

Comment: For the case insensitivity - you need h.add(term.lower())

Comment: But is that case-insensitive? If I add a "print h" line at the end, for a sample file, I get: 

4
set(['bar', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'foo']).

Foo and foo should be the same.

Comment: Ah, I'm too slow guys, let me check your comments.

Comment: Cool, I never even knew about set

Comment: If you like oneliners, then the following is equivalent:
import sys
print len(set(term.lower() for line in sys.stdin for term in line.split()))

Comment: The perl version needs $H{lc($_)} for case insensitive as well.

Answer (score 6):

In Perl:

```
my %words; 
while (<>) { 
    map { $words{lc $_} = 1 } split /\s/); 
} 
print scalar keys %words, "\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

Using bash/UNIX commands:

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\+/\n/g' $FILE | sort -fu | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

Using just standard Unix utilities:

```
< somefile tr 'A-Z[:blank:][:punct:]' 'a-z\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

If you're on a system without Gnu `tr`, you'll need to replace "`[:blank:][:punct:]`" with a list of all the whitespace and punctuation characters you'd like to consider to be separators of words, rather than part of a word, e.g., "`\t.,;`".

If you want the output sorted in descending order of frequency, you can append "`| sort -r -n`" to the end of this.

Note that this will produce an irrelevant count of whitespace tokens as well; if you're concerned about this, after the `tr` you can use sed to filter out the empty lines.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '$h{lc $_}++ for split /[\s.,]+/; END{print scalar keys %h}' file.txt
```

Or to list the count for each item:

```
perl -lne '$h{lc $_}++ for split /[\s.,]+/; END{printf "%-12s %d\n", $_, $h{$_} for sort keys %h}' file.txt
```

This makes an attempt to handle punctuation so that "foo." is counted with "foo" while "don't" is treated as a single word, but you can adjust the regex to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Simply (52 strokes):

```
perl -nE'@w{map lc,split/\W+/}=();END{say 0+keys%w}'
```

For older perl versions (55 strokes):

```
perl -lne'@w{map lc,split/\W+/}=();END{print 0+keys%w}'
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version in Python:

```
print len(set(w.lower() for w in open('filename.dat').read().split()))
```

Reads the entire file into memory, splits it into words using whitespace, converts each word to lower case, creates a (unique) set from the lowercase words, counts them and prints the output.

Also possible using a one liner:

```
python -c "print len(set(w.lower() for w in open('filename.dat').read().split()))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk oneliner.

```
$ gawk -v RS='[[:space:]]' 'NF&&!a[toupper($0)]++{i++}END{print i}' somefile
```

- 'NF' means 'if there is a charactor'.
- '!a[topuuer[$0]++]' means 'show only 
  uniq words'.