# Counting the number of unique words in a document with Python

Tags: python

I am  Python newbie trying to understand the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914382/how-can-i-count-unique-terms-in-a-plaintext-file-case-insensitively/930185#930185) to the question of counting unique words in a document. The answer is:

```
print len(set(w.lower() for w in open('filename.dat').read().split()))
```

> Reads the entire file into memory, splits it into words using
>   whitespace, converts each word to lower case, creates a (unique) set
>   from the lowercase words, counts them and prints the output

To try understand that, I am trying to implement it in Python step by step. I can import the text tile using open and read, divide it into individual words using split, and make them all lower case using lower. I can also create a set of the unique words in the list. However, I cannot figure out how to do the last part - count the number of unique words.

I thought I could finish by iterating through the items in the set of unique words and counting them in the original lower-case list, but I find that that the set construct is not indexable.

So I guess I am trying to do something that in natural language is like, for all the items in the set, tell me how many times they occur in the lower case list. But I cannot quite figure out how to do that, and I suspect some underlying misunderstanding of Python is holding me back.

- EDIT -

Guys thanks for the answers. I have just realised I did not explain myself correctly - I wanted to find not only the total number of unique words (which I understand is the length of the set) but also the number of times each individual word was used, e.g. 'the' was used 14 times, 'and' was used 9 times, 'it' was used 20 times and so on. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Why aren't you using a dictionary to map from word to count?

Comment: There's no need to iterate through the set to count the number of unique words. That's what the `len` function does - it gives you the length of the set.

Comment: What's wrong with `unique_word_count = len(your_set)`?

Comment: S. Lott - I think what you are suggesting is what I actually meant, see edit in the question above.

Answer (score 21):

I believe that [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) is all that you need in this case:

```
from collections import Counter

print Counter(yourtext.split())
```

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the number of items in a set, list or tuple all the same with `len(my_set)` or `len(my_list)`.

Edit: Calculating the numbers of times a word is used, is something different.
Here the obvious approach:

```
count = {}
for w in open('filename.dat').read().split():
    if w in count:
        count[w] += 1
    else:
        count[w] = 1
for word, times in count.items():
    print "%s was found %d times" % (word, times)
```

If you want to avoid the if-clause, you can look at [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: Wouldn't this count the same word that occurs at the end of the sentence versus the middle of the sentence as two different unique words? Which is not the behaviour you'd want. E.g. "traffic" and "traffic." would be counted as separate unique words.

Comment: @geominded Sure, this is a somewhat naive approach. But the topic of the question was about counting words. You probably would use extra effort to make sure that you count the right words.
Btw. today I think Artsioms answer (using collections.Counter) is much better.

Answer (score 4):

A [**set**](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#set-objects), by definition, contains unique elements (in your case, you can't find the same *'lower cased string'* twice there). So, what you have to do is simply get the count of elements in the set = the length of the set = `len(set(...))`

Answer (score 2):

Your question already contains the answer. If `s` is the set of unique words in the document, then `len(s)` gives the number of elements in the set, i.e. *the number of unique words in the document*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(['mama','papa','mama'])
```

The result of c will be

```
Counter({'mama': 2, 'papa': 1})
```

Comment: This is a repetition of @ArtsiomRudzenka's answer in 2011, the only difference is that the result is shown here, which would have to be an edit or comment, not an answer. (I understand you cannot do that < 50 points). Still: your answer is a repetition.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

```
len(set(open(file_path).read().lower().split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this can be used to get a unique word count. Works fine with python 3.10.2

```py
from collections import Counter

def get_count_of_unique_words(lines):
    selected_words = []
    for word in lines:
        if word.isalpha():
           selected_words.append(word)

    unique_count = 0
    for letter, count in Counter(selected_words).items():
        if count == 1:
            unique_count += 1

    print(unique_count)
    return unique_count
```

Docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

I would say that that code counts the number of *distinct* words, not the number of *unique* words, which is the number of words which occur only once.

This counts the number of times that each word occurs:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_counts = defaultdict(int)

for w in open('filename.dat').read().split():
    word_counts[w.lower()] += 1

for w, c in word_counts.iteritems():
    print w, "occurs", word_counts[w], "times"
```